# What does "pulls together a distance in dialogue" means?

Tags: idioms

It was a sociotype description:

"TECHNOLOGIST (Si-ESTj)
The sensory subtype is characterized by a differentiation between their internal stability and working capacity. Internally unstable, they are likewise extremely vigorous and cannot relax without business affairs as they do not like wasting time in vain. Interested in new technologies within the professional sphere and able to adapt these to serve their needs. Possess a sense of humor. Their speech is abrupt and emotional; their smile is somewhat tense. ***Pulls together distance in dialogue*** through hospitable, friendly gestures - embraces and light touches. Briskly conducts conversation and/or jokes. An aesthete with a taste for gourmet, they love original dishes and beautiful, expensive objects of quality. Are able to relieve pressures by sitting at a table with friends but rarely allow themselves the rest to themselves that they need. Have a tendency to corpulence, their movements are gusty, sharp, quick and impulsive; often embody a restless demeanor." 
http://www.the16types.info/vbulletin/content.php/14-Type-and-subtype-descriptions-Meged-Ovcharov

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say what it means.  I wouldn't worry about it as your link takes me to a site about a modern-day pseudoscience called *socionics*, which purports to describe personality types and which appears to be phrenology re-cast.  Check out the [logo](http://www.the16types.info/vbulletin/attachment.php?attachmentid=5921&cid=24&thumb=1&stc=1) for this field of study.  The authors are Russian, and their English on the site has many idiomatic failures.  You probably need to be able to read the original in the original language to be sure what your phrase means.